# how to debug ldap over ssl on Solaris 10

Tags: active-directory, ldap, solaris, ldap-query, solaris-10

I need to debug ldaps connect to a AD server which use SSL certificates from a Solaris 10 box.

I tried this command:

```
  /bin/ldapsearch -h aduat.888.com -p 636 -Z -P /u01/cfg/cacerts -s sub -b  "uid=my_name,o=888,c=ca"  "(objectclass=*)" -v
```

/u01/cfg/cacerts is a jks keystore which contains the LDAP server's certificates.

and get this error message:

```
 SSL initialization failed: error -8015 (unknown)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using `ldapsearch` with the `-Z` STARTTLS option against the LDAPS port, which is "native" SSL that doesn't use STARTTLS.  Per https://wiki.wireshark.org/LDAP:

> **Protocol dependencies**
>
> - TCP/UDP: Typically, LDAP uses TCP or UDP (aka CLDAP) as its transport protocol. **The well known TCP and UDP port for LDAP traffic
>     is 389.**
> - SSL/TLS: LDAP can also be tunneled through SSL/TLS encrypted connections. **The well known TCP port for SSL is 636** while TLS is
>     negotiated within a plain TCP connection on port 389.

Per [the Solaris `ldapsearch` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/ldapsearch-1.html):

*

> *Options**
>
> The following options are supported:
>
> ...
>
> -h *ldaphost*
>
> Specify an alternate host on which the secure LDAP server is running.

From my reading of all that, you need to use `-h 636` instead of `-Z -p 636`.